# ATmega freezes because of power supply

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, transient-suppression

I'm using a 10W/12V PCB mount SMPS for a project. In the same board I'm using an ATMEGA2560. When there is a power fluctuation, the ATmega freezes and all the communication is halted. How can I fix this problem?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: USe a better power supply and remove it  or add a Line filter or show layout in photo and all datasheet links and load schematics with measurement techniques for possible errors. Also any inductive switching noise nearby?

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 There are some inductive loads connected next to it.

Comment: What kind of power supply are you using? Where do the power spikes come from. What is your schematic an layout (do you have capacitors near the supply lines of the ATmega?)

Comment: You have many problems but lack necessary details above to answer it

Comment: These are some generic solutions https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/49824/microcontroller-with-a-long-wire-for-digital-input/49825#49825

Comment: Also twisted pair cables at right angles crosstalk less

Comment: @kruemi I am using ECE10US12 by XPpower.

Comment: your layout is the problem

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Attached schematics for more info. Hope this helps.

Comment: The logic diagram is not a physical layout. Show detailed photos and measurement probes with Gnd location

Comment: @Lex - Hi, In future, when you are asked to supply more details, please edit *that* question to improve it - don't delete that one and post an updated version. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The Schematic looks ok. So it's most likely down to the layout.

1. Reduce interfence power
2. Make your circuit more resitant to interference

- If there are inductive loads powered by DC, give them [freewheeling diodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyback_diode). If they are powered by AC use [snubbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snubber)
- For the switching power regulator, use the layout guides the supplier of the component suggests. Don't do anything fancy.
- The capacitances must be close to the VCC pins. Keep Power and Ground traces as short as possible and keep the close together.